# transform object to object array with ramdajs

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I am writing a program, counting words in a file.

Suppose the object likes this:

```
{
  I: 2,
  it: 4,
  that: 1
}
```

And I wanna make it:

```
[
  { word: 'I', count: 2 }, 
  { word: 'it', count: 4 }, 
  { word: 'that', count: 1 }
]
```

**I can achieve the goal by using imperative programming**: loop the object...

And I **check out the docs and google**, but can't find any method fit in :(

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved using [`R.toPairs`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#toPairs) and [`R.zipObj`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#zipObj):

```
//    convert :: {a} -> [{ word :: String, count :: a }]
const convert = R.compose(R.map(R.zipObj(['word', 'count'])), R.toPairs);

convert({I: 2, it: 4, that: 1});
// => [{"count": 2, "word": "I"}, {"count": 4, "word": "it"}, {"count": 1, "word": "that"}]
```

Comment: cool~ BTW, how should I learn ramdajs?  I can't find any resources except the official site, and I can't always ask the questions in here.

Comment: The [Gitter room](https://gitter.im/ramda/ramda) is quite active, and the people there are very helpful. Also, Brian Lonsdorf has created many wonderful resources for learning about functional programming in JavaScript. Have a look for his various tutorials, talks, and screencasts.